# Error deploying Azure Communication Service with Email Services and Managed Domain using Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-bicep, azure-communication-services

As the title states I'm trying to use bicep to deploy an Azure Communiction service and link it to an Email Service with Azure-managed domain. My script is able to create all ressources, but it fails when trying to link the communication service to the domain with the error:

`"The specified domain is unable to be linked."`

The really interesting part: The domain shows as correctly linked in the Communication Service.

I've tried using the `2023-04-01-preview` api but this fails because it doesn't let me set location as global...

Here's my full bicep:

```
var communicationServiceName = 'cs-medienstudio-dev'
var emailServiceName = 'es-medienstudio-dev'

resource emailService 'Microsoft.Communication/emailServices@2023-03-31' = {
  name: emailServiceName
  location: 'global'
  properties: {
    dataLocation: 'Europe'
  }
}

resource emailServiceDomain 'Microsoft.Communication/emailServices/domains@2023-03-31' = {
  parent: emailService
  name: 'AzureManagedDomain'
  location: 'global'
  properties: {
    domainManagement: 'AzureManaged'
  }
}

resource senderUserName 'Microsoft.Communication/emailServices/domains/senderUsernames@2023-03-31' = {
  parent: emailServiceDomain
  name: 'donotreply'
  properties:{
    username: 'DoNotReply'
    displayName: 'DoNotReply'
  }
}

resource communcationService 'Microsoft.Communication/communicationServices@2023-03-31' = {
  name: communicationServiceName
  location: 'global'
  properties: {
    dataLocation: 'Germany'
    linkedDomains: [
      emailServiceDomain.id
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If someone ends up here because they encounter this error while deploying a CustomerManaged domain, you will have to do the verification of the domain records before attempting to deploy again. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/email/add-custom-verified-domains

Answer (score 1):

Please try by appending `/domains/AzureManagedDomain` to the `emailServiceDomain.id` in `linkedDomains`. So the bicep code for creating communication service could be something like:

```
resource communcationService 'Microsoft.Communication/communicationServices@2023-03-31' = {
  name: communicationServiceName
  location: 'global'
  properties: {
    dataLocation: 'Germany'
    linkedDomains: [
      join([emailServiceDomain.id, '/domains/AzureManagedDomain'], '')
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: seems like this was indeed the issue, thanks

Comment: actually, I checked again and while it was not failing it didn't link correctly. emailServiceDomain.id should suffice